# How do I get a button press to instantly run it's if statement

Tags: python, button

this is my first time using stack overflow and I'm relatively new to python as well, I'm running a while=true statement checking for temp and also checking for button presses, the problem is I have to hold the button until it's finished getting the temp and checks if the button is pressed, how do I make it so when I click the button it will instantly run it's bit of code?
Thanks- beginner

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
import time
b = 38
r = 40
import Freenove_DHT as DHT
DHTPin = 11
dht = DHT.DHT(DHTPin)
Hitemp = 75
Lotemp = 70
GPIO.setup(b, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(r, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
b1 = 31
b2 = 32
b3 = 18
GPIO.setup(b1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(b3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(b2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
while(True):           
            chk = dht.readDHT11()     #read DHT11 and get a return value. 
            time.sleep(0.1)
            Ctemp = float(("%.2f \n"%(dht.temperature)))
            Ftemp = 1.8*(Ctemp) + 32
            print (Ftemp)
            if Ftemp > Hitemp:
                GPIO.output(b, GPIO.HIGH)
                GPIO.output(r, GPIO.LOW)
            elif Ftemp < Lotemp:
                GPIO.output(r, GPIO.HIGH)
                GPIO.output(b, GPIO.LOW)
            else:
                GPIO.output(r, GPIO.LOW)
                GPIO.output(b, GPIO.LOW)
            if GPIO.input(b1)==GPIO.HIGH:
                print("Button Press1")
            if GPIO.input(b2)==GPIO.HIGH:
                print("Button Press2")
            if GPIO.input(b3)==GPIO.HIGH:
                print("Button Press3")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Instead of describing what your code does, please post the code itself: see [mcve]

Comment: maybe you should use button only to set some boolean variable - `already_pressed = True` - and later only check this variable. And if other code need longer time then it will need to run separated thread to check button and set boolean variable. See module `threading`